# Problema con entity framework al generar el modelo desde la base de datos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, base-de-datos, entity-framework

No me deja seleccionar las tablas del modelo, ya verifique y la conexión esta bien hecha, alguna otra solución? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te deja selecionar tablas porque en realidad no esta listando ninguna

Como veras en la imagen, si hay tablas deberias poder desplegar el listado, en la imagen que muestras no hay tablas que desplegar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

valida que la db a la cual te conectas tiene tablas definidas